# Firebase Recycler Paging Adapter duplicating last item

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

i am trying to implement an endless firebase recycler, it is working fine when there are multiple items, but if i have a low number of items in the list, it will start duplicating a random item to make it endless, here is the config for the adapter

```
val config: PagedList.Config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPrefetchDistance(1)
        .setPageSize(15)
        .build()
```

and here's an image of the current result, notice that the 2nd item is duplicating while the 3rd isn't, all the while the 4th item cannot be found at all

[image]

and these are the current items on the firebase database

[image]

here's the query for the data

```
dataBase.child(USERS).child(userId!!).child(TRANSACTIONS).orderByChild("dateInMillis")
```

and this is the adapter class

```
class DashboardAdapter(
options: DatabasePagingOptions<Transaction>,
val itemCallback: (transaction: Transaction) -> Unit
) :
FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<Transaction, DashboardAdapter.DashboardViewHolder>(options) {

private val TAG = DashboardAdapter::class.simpleName

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DashboardViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding =
        TransactionItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
    return DashboardViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(
    viewHolder: DashboardViewHolder,
    position: Int,
    model: Transaction
) {
    viewHolder.binding.transaction = model
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        itemCallback(model)
    }
}

class DashboardViewHolder(val binding: TransactionItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onLoadingStateChanged(state: LoadingState) {
    when (state) {
        LoadingState.LOADING_INITIAL -> Log.d(TAG, "onLoadingStateChanged: test")
        LoadingState.LOADING_MORE -> Log.d(TAG, "onLoadingStateChanged: test")
        LoadingState.LOADED -> Log.d(TAG, "onLoadingStateChanged: test")
        LoadingState.FINISHED -> Log.d(TAG, "onLoadingStateChanged: test")
        LoadingState.ERROR -> Log.d(TAG, "onLoadingStateChanged: test")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: show should also post adapter code and query

Comment: added them, don't see a need for the adapter class tho

Comment: i noticed that this issue happens when i use orderByChild only